# Experiences and authentication experiences adding a struts2 web application as an App (HTML) to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin, oauth

from my question title, you can tell I have no experience developing web applications for SharePoint applications

Per requirements, I need to develop Java Web Applications (run on its own Tomcat Server, etc..) to be used as Apps(1) within the SharePoint Site/App. The Apps basically help users fill out forms stored on the SharePoint (content) server by removing unnecessary questions asked in the forms.

My questions are:

Under the Assumption: User will authentication to the SharePoint App Site with Claims Based Windows Integrated Authentication (Kerberos Negotiate setting)

1. I am assuming they have to be Provider Hosted Apps (Since hosted remotely locally)?
2. What type of authentication can I implement between the Web Application and SharePoint Server (for REST calls) if users use the SharePoint Main App through Windows Integrated Authentication?
3. I have looked into only OAuth in detail, An example here shows off OAuth http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/authorization-and-authentication-for-apps-in-sharepoint-2013/ . Would it be a good path to follow?
4. Are there any recommended, end user based or claims based authentication method to look into ?